# Flash Player for other browsers

Tags: package-management, flash

How can I get flash player for other browsers in Ubuntu? I've trued flashplayer-installer, adobe-flashplugin, any ideas lads?

Comment: `flashplayer-installer` should work for Chromium (except Trusty) and Firefox. Can you give a few more details (Ubuntu version, browsers, etc.)?

Comment: Wanting to use it on Garry's Mod, or is this Windows only?

Comment: Wait, a physics game? That's not a browser.

Comment: Garry's Mod PlayX, I think I may have fixed it using the 32bit packages, checking it now.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe has now announced that they will remove Flash Player for Linux and make it available only for Google Chrome. Adobe agreement with Google to release a plugin dedicated to Chrome (available for both 32-bit and 64-bit) through Pepper Plugin API (PPAPI) with which they can benefit other browser. In the next few hours Flash Player for Linux will be removed from the official repositories of Adobe

**Install Lightspark Instead.**
Lightspark is an LGPLv3 licensed Flash player and browser plugin written in C++/C that runs on Linux. It aims to support Adobe's newer Flash formats and AVM2 virtual machine.

Try this on your terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sparkers/daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lightspark browser-plugin-lightspark
```

or check the project page:
[sourceforge.net/projects/lightspark/](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lightspark/)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer but it wasn't what I was asking but will answer it anyway. Thanks much!

Comment: Ubuntu and packages are about dependencies ! So are the users. We should be updated and not risk ourselves on programs that will not continue updating. One level of dependency less for us !

Answer (score 0):

Adobe no longer develops Flash Player Plugin for Linux. The only way to have latest plugin in Linux is to use Google Chrome browser.

The last version for Linux that you can install with that packages is 11.2. The latest version of Flash is 13.

Comment: That's not the *only* way. See [this](https://launchpad.net/~skunk/+archive/pepper-flash) PPA.

Comment: @saiarcot895 does it work with Firefox? I mean does firefox or other browsers than chromium support Pepper API?

Comment: No, browsers other than Chrome(ium) don't support Pepper API, as far as I know.

Comment: @saiarcot895 Opera should work with it. Isn't Chromium based?

Comment: I know it is Blink-based, and if the Pepper API code is in Blink, then it should be supported in Opera, but I'm not entirely sure on that. Correction: as per [this](http://operabrowser.wikispaces.com/Features) page, Opera supports Pepper API in 15.0.1147.18.